# How to get item in REST API by multiple item id

Tags: api, rest

I have product_id and onec_id columns to get items from DB. Which API routes should I use to get items by product_id or by onec_id?

Is it right for REST routes?

```
GET /products/{product_id}
GET /products/get_by_onec_id/{onec_id}
```

Comment: What Resources are identified by these IDs? What do you mean by 'multiple item id'?

Comment: I need to get products in two ways:
- by product_id
- by onec_id

Comment: Are you writing an api or consuming one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most REST solution is to fire one HTTP request for each id. For example

```
GET /product/736
```

REST is intended to represent the state of a resource. It can return a set of items, but only if these items relate to each other in some way. For example

```
GET /onec/492/products
```

Will return the set of products associated with the specified onec.

If you want to return the set of products identified by a set of IDs in a single request, you may have your shortcut syntax like

```
GET /products/12,768,56,086
```

But it's not really common because it's quite a departure from the REST objectives

Comment: decided to write routes in such way:
`GET /product/id/:id`
`GET /product/onec/:id`

Answer (score 1):

To get a single Product or Onec(?), `GET`

```
/products/{id}
/onecs/{id}
```